# Take a specific part of a matrix, excluding the external brackets

Tags: matrix, symbolic, algebra

I have a little manipulation problem.
I have the following matrix:

```
mat = RandomInteger[10, {4, 5}];
mat 
{{8, 6, 2, 8, 0}, {1, 4, 2, 5, 7}, {6, 3, 4, 4, 7}, {6, 4, 7, 9, 9}}
```

Then I want to store every row sequentially in a vector called vecint like:

```
vecint[1]={8, 6, 2, 8, 0}
vecint[2]={8, 6, 2, 8, 0}, {1, 4, 2, 5, 7}
```

I have tried something like the following:

```
For[i = 1, i < 3, i++, vecint[i] = mat[[1 ;; i, 1 ;; 5]]]
```

It gives:

```
vecint[1]={8, 6, 2, 8, 0}
vecint[2]={{8, 6, 2, 8, 0}, {1, 4, 2, 5, 7}}
```

vecint[1] is correct, but vecint[2] has two curly brackets in excess.
There is a way to do this operation?

Thanks for any helps and tips!

You can use Sequence and Evaluate to put in parameter lists into Integrate. For example: params = {{x, 0, 1}, {y, 2, 3}}; Integrate[Sin[x] Cos[y], Sequence @@ params] will splat those parameters on the end of the Integrate

Comment: I think you're a bit confused about the brackets. `vecint[2]={8, 6, 2, 8, 0}, {1, 4, 2, 5, 7}` isn't even valid syntax. The extra `{ ... }` are necessary because it is a `List` of `List`. Mathematica doesn't have vectors or matrices as distinct objects, it only has lists. [Please read this](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Lists.html).

Comment: I understand what you mean, but i have to use vecint[i] like the parameter of a multiple integration. For example if i can define vecint[2]={x,1,2},{y,2,3} i can write the integration like this: Integrate[x+y,vecint[2]]

Comment: It is emerging as an [XY](https://xyproblem.info/) problem. Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please edit your post to include a good description of what you want to do.

Comment: ^^ you should mention this in your question. Please edit it. You can use Sequence and Evaluate to put in parameter lists into Integrate. For example: `params = {{x, 0, 1}, {y, 2, 3}};
Integrate[Sin[x] Cos[y], Sequence @@ params]` will _splat_ those parameters on the end of the `Integrate`. Doing `Integrate` with variable parameter lists has been asked before so I will vote to close.

Comment: Thanks, I am new here and i don't know how to mention your comment in my question...

Comment: @LorenzoBagnasacco use the 'Edit' button. https://imgur.com/a/4riRoNG

Comment: Now I try to do the same thing below for NIntegrate, but it doesen't work...